# IndexOutOfBoundsException when loading FXML because of a binding

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I'm building a JavaFX application and I'm using bingings. Everything works fine but this one line throws an exception.

`ExportarControlador.class`:

```
//List of loaded images, it contains information to find the real image file
private ObservableList<ImgBean> list;

//Indicator to mark which image from the list should be displayed now
private SimpleIntegerProperty indicator;

@FXML private ImageView imageView;

//...

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){

    //...   

    imageView.imageProperty().bind(Bindings.when(
                Bindings.isEmpty(list))
                .then(new SimpleObjectProperty<ImgBean>())
                .otherwise(new SimpleObjectProperty<ImgBean>(new Image(someUtils.getURLFromImgBean(list.get(indicator.get()))))));

    //...
}
```

The idea behind this is that the binding should check the `ObservableList`. When the list is empty, the `ImageView` displays no image. When the list has images, the `ImageView` should display the image `list.get(indicator)`. Indicator can never be `< 0` or `>= list.size()`, I have checked that. This is the stacktrace.

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/[path-to-my-project]/exportar.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.bcadaval.memefinder3020.principal.SpringFxmlLoader.cargaVistas(SpringFxmlLoader.java:50) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.bcadaval.memefinder3020.concurrencia.TaskSplash.call(TaskSplash.java:68) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.bcadaval.memefinder3020.concurrencia.TaskSplash.call(TaskSplash.java:1) ~[classes/:?]
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    at com.bcadaval.memefinder3020.controlador.ExportarControlador.initialize(ExportarControlador.java:156) ~[classes/:?]
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548) ~[jfxrt.jar:?]
    ... 8 more
```

Obviously the cause of the exception is, somehow, `.otherwise()` is called, but it has no sense, because the list is always empty unless I click a button that populates it, so `.then()` should be the only method called.

Didn't I bind `.otherwise()` properly? Am I missing any other way to achieve the same result that is way simpler? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bindings.when(...)` fluent API does not behave as a shortcut operator: in other words it will evaluate the `otherwise()` clause even if the condition in the `when()` clause is true (and conversely, will evaluate the `then()` clause even if the `when()` clause is false).

Instead, you can just create a custom binding directly:

```
imageView.imageProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return null ;
    } else {
        int index = indicator.get();
        ImgBean imgBean = list.get(index);
        URL imageUrl = someUtils.getURLFromImgBean(imgBean);
        return new Image(imageUrl);
    }
}, list, indicator);
```

You can also use this fairly easily to check the index is in bounds, if you need.